# Laravel: pluck method on Model instance

Tags: laravel

I am just learning about Laravel, so excuse me for any newbie questions. In a tutorial I have seen people using `pluck` directly on Model classes, such as `App\MyModel::pluck('id')`.

My question is where the class gets this method from. It extends the `Model` class but neither there nor in any trait is it defined. I can only see it defined for collections. I have looked at the source intensely but cannot see it.

Thanks
Zibellon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of Laravel models they do extend a base class named Model. Example when you define a model the class will look like

```
class Channel extends Model
{

   //stuff

}
```

Class `channel` extends base class `Model`, if you go to Model base class you will find it under `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

That is the abstract base Model class which through some magic methods it recalls the method defined on `QueryBuilder` under `'Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder'` there method `pluck` is defined

Comment: Thank you Leo. Exactly this is my question, where do I see the magic methods that are used to include the methods defined for 'Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder'.

Comment: I found it now with your hint. The __call magic method will actually use the query builder, it makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: __call :)  is the one